# Name of decomposition $A=BB^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

Suppose $A$ is a $d\times d$ matrix. My application requires finding the following decomposition. Does it have a name?

$$A=BB^T$$

Matrix $B$ is not required to be symmetric/triangular/skinny.

**Edit** the application is iteratively reweighted least squared. For logistic regression/scalar output, I can reweigh each example $x$ by by $\sqrt{g''(x)}$ and treat it as regular least squares. When moving to multiclass case, the Hessian $g''$ is now a matrix, and I need to replace $\sqrt{\cdot}$ by this decomposition. I would call it "square root", but this name is already taken. For the most common loss (softmax), $B$ can be chosen as a sum of a diagonal and a rank-1 matrix.

Comment: Not an arbitrary matrix $A$ admits such a decomposition. In fact, $A$ itself has to be positive semi-definite and symmetric (as can be seen from $A = BB^T$).

Answer (score 1):

Of course, [Cholesky's decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) gives you something of the form $A = LL^T$, where $L$ is lower triangular; every other such decomposition is of the form $A = BB^T$ with $B = LU$ for some orthogonal matrix $U$.

I do not believe that freedom in the choice of $B$ leads to any computational improvements over the usual Cholesky method, which is hard to beat. I do not know of a name for this more general form of decomposition.

Comment: Interesting that it doesn't have a name. I've added clarification where this decomposition comes up.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov If you want to invent a term, you could perhaps call it a "positive" or "positivity revealing" factorization in analogy to the ["rank" or "rank-revealing" factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_factorization).